# Java test coverage: who covers what?

Tags: java, unit-testing, static-analysis, emma

Is there a tool similar to emma, that reports *which* test covers a specific implementation ?

Comment: I would use a debugger to break point the line of code and run your tests to see which test is running then it hits that line of code.

Comment: 1.500.000 LOC, 50-70% aggregated test-coverage (itest+unittest). currently trying to increase / understand test-coverage of one module with 30.000 LOC. I need some good report, not individual manual tries ...

Comment: Can you run groups of tests at a time and examine the report for that group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you want to see, which tests cover which line of code, you may use [Clover](http://www.atlassian.com/software/clover/overview)
that shows you:

- how many times one line got covered
- which tests covered line in question

To see what one can expect from Clover, here is a screenshot:
[image: Clover coverage report. Opened info about test that hit line #49]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to bother paying / setting up Cover, a **much simpler way** is:

- remove / disable all breakpoints
- put a breakpoint on the line that you which to know the tests covering it
- re-run the tests in debug mode
- look at the stacktrace to find the test calling it

This methods also allows you to see how many times a line is covered and all the tests calling it.